# create 32 bit using 64 bit netbeans javapackager

Tags: swing, netbeans, 32bit-64bit, javapackager

i have a java swing application made using

- netbeans (jdk1.8.0_111)
- jre1.8.0_111
- pavapckager to create exe file
- application has some library's

[image]

When i package i get a 64bit installer using javapackager which is expected.
I am trying to create a 32bit installer.
i have tried:

- installing 32 bit jre and jdk
- setting path to the 32bit version
- changing netbeans config to use:
  netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111"
- using :  -Bruntime="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre" in the javapackager

How do i create a 32 bit Self-Contained Application Packaging using javapackager on a 64 bit windows system using netbeans

Answer (score 1):

after restarting my pc everything started to work.

this is what i done:

- Install 32 bit jdk and jre
- In netbeans project add a new platform and choose the 32 bit version (restart pc)
- Install inno and set path.
- run javapackager specifing the 32 bit i.e javapackager -deploy -native exe -B
  systemWide=true -Bruntime="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre" -Bshort
  cutHint=true -outdir packages ...etc
- test with Exe64bitDetector