# Generate exe for 32-bit system of Java software

Tags: java, swing, exe, development-environment, software-distribution

I have built a Java Swing application using Netbeans. I am able to generate a exe for 64-bit systems and it is working perfectly. But I am unable to generate exe for 32-bit systems because I am using a 64-bit system. So what can I do to generate the respective 32-bit exe?

Comment: *"GENERATE EXE FOR 32-BIT SYSTEM OF JAVA SOFTWARE"* There is no need to **SHOUT** at us!

Comment: What do you mean by this statement Andrew Thompson

Comment: 1) Words typed in all lower case are hard to read, like trying to listen to someone who is mumbling.  Please use an upper case letter at the start of sentences, for the word I, and proper names like `ArrayList` or Oracle. You demonstrated knowledge of this in the body of your question and in that comment. But.. 2) DON'T USE ALL UPPER CASE EITHER, AS THAT IS LIKE SHOUTING AT US! There is no need to **shout** and all it achieves is to make people angry. (I edited the title to remove the shouting.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an answer for JDK 1.8 here: [create 32 bit using 64 bit netbeans javapackager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41701328/create-32-bit-using-64-bit-netbeans-javapackager)

First you have to install the 32-bit JDK and JRE besides the 64-bit ones, in order to allow the IDE to give 32-bit as an option. (If that's what you want)

> ```
> Install 32 bit jdk and jre
> In netbeans project add a new platform and choose the 32 bit version (restart pc)
> Install inno and set path.
> run javapackager specifing the 32 bit i.e javapackager -deploy -native exe -B systemWide=true -Bruntime="C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre" -Bshort cutHint=true -outdir packages
> ```
>
> ...etc
> test with Exe64bitDetector

Another option is to use Launch4j: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/

https://github.com/fabnicolas/launch4j_exe_tutorial

Comment: NP! BTW, if that helps you or solves your problem, you can mark the answer.